# Black screen after disabling Intel graphics on ASUS laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, safe-mode, black-screen-of-death

My ASUS A53SV laptop has an onboard Intel GMA graphics and also nVidia GeForce 540N. I am using Windows 7 Pro. I thought that the GeForce was not being used, so I went to Device Manager and disabled Intel graphics.

After that, my screen turned black and I could't see anything. I turned the laptop off and turned it on again – 'Resuming Windows' logo appears and then I only see a blinking cursor on a black screen.

I can't get into safe mode by hitting F8 and I can't enter BIOS either as usually (by holding Alt+F2 when ASUS logo splashes).

Comment: hmm, but why doesn't F8 work?

Comment: @XLL Hell, how do I know? I am more concerned about BIOS...

Comment: I don't think Windows will have altered your ability to get into the bios.  The Asus site says Del is the key to get into the bios.

Comment: Just FYI, in an Optimus setup (Intel + NVIDIA) Intel is *always* used. Screen is connected to Intel graphics, NVIDIA GPU is used only for rendering frames which are then displayed by Intel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by switching off my laptop definetely by holding power button. After that, I was able to get into safe mode and restoring both video controllers in Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In last resort you may want to restore the BIOS to its default settings:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5024662_reset-asus-motherboard.html

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is reset the BIOS.

Disconnect all power soures (power cable, monitor, powered speakers).
Press the power button to discharge any residual power in the system.
Open the case, and locate the battery on your motherboard.
Pop the battery out. What 1 minute. Put the battery back in the slot.
Put the case back on and reconnect everything.
Power on.

Your BIOS should be in a default state with the integrated video working again.

Good luck!

Source - http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1852644/accidently-disabled-intel-graphics.html